# Partial fraction decomposition for multivariate rational functions

Tags: partial-fractions, multivariate-polynomial

Is there an analogue of partial fractions for **multivariate** rational functions?

For example, what would be a good way to express $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x+y)(x-y)}$?

Comment: Here is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.08283.pdf) which discusses ways to decompose multivariate rational functions.